# Python Matrix Multiplication By Flattening Matrices

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, flatten

I have two matrices. One of them has size (128, 3, 32, 49) and the other one is (128, 3, 49, 32). In normal version, matrix multiplication of these matrices has size (128,3,32,32).

I want to pack one of these matrices such that the modified matrix has 2-D size like (x,y). Then I want to multiply matrices. Is there any way to do that? How can I do that in Python?

I have done some flattening operations, however I could not finalize matrix multiplication. Size gets bigger such that I don't understand when I use flattening.

Comment: What should be the final dimension of your matrix?

Comment: It should be  (128,3,32,32). There may be some processes such that final size becomes  (128,3,32,32). The only rule is to create  (128,3,32,32).

Comment: Check the solution below

Comment: I have checked your answer and I wrote an answer

Answer (score 0):

No need of flattening your matrices. The question is incorrectly labeled thats why you have very few interraction. Directly use `@` or simply [`einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).The notion of flattening your matrix is an [`xyproblem`](https://xyproblem.info/).

As you have a 4 dimensional array, use the code:

```
import numpy as np
A @ B
np.einsum('abcd,abde->abce', A, B)
```

---

Example

```
np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.rand(32).reshape(2, 2,2,4)
B = np.random.rand(32).reshape(2, 2,4,2)
np.einsum('abcd,abde->abce', A, B)
array([[[[0.9034447 , 0.67650381],
         [0.33865041, 0.52205739]],

        [[1.20931496, 1.11106936],
         [1.06044851, 1.05516956]]],


       [[[0.25800135, 0.48137054],
         [0.6558434 , 0.88158288]],

        [[1.0661697 , 0.80598857],
         [0.91747834, 0.85454168]]]])
```

Now Computing each matrix by hand:

```
A[0, 0] @ B[0, 0]
array([[0.9034447 , 0.67650381],
       [0.33865041, 0.52205739]])

 A[0, 1] @ B[0, 1]
array([[1.20931496, 1.11106936],
       [1.06044851, 1.05516956]])

A[1, 0] @ B[1, 0]
array([[0.25800135, 0.48137054],
       [0.6558434 , 0.88158288]])

A[1, 1] @ B[1, 1]
array([[1.0661697 , 0.80598857],
       [0.91747834, 0.85454168]]
```

Comment: It is my first post, that is why I could not define tag very well, sorry about that. For the question, I think I was not clear enough. I want a modification for one of the matrix such that it is shaped as (x,y). So, for example, for my first example, I want  (128, 3, 32, 49) as (128*3*32,49). After that, I want to make a matrix multiplication with the other one. Then, I want to have  (128,3,32,32) shape result.

Comment: Is there any way such that first vector is reshaped as (128*3*32,49) and the other one is (128,3,49,32) with the help of np.einsum?

Comment: @DOLFIN Why do you want to reshape? The method given above solves the problem. You will end up with `(128, 3, 32, 32)` matrix. In the example above, A.shape is (2,2,2,4) and B.shape is (2,2,4,2). After the multiplication i end up with (2,2,2,2)~

Comment: Actually, I should have given more details. I have `(128,3,32,49)` array and I am doing a clustering operation on this array. In order it to be more efficient, I reshape `(128,3,32,49)` as `(128*3*32, 49)`.So after I reshape this matrix and I cluster row data, I have a matrix which have shape like `(X, 49)`. So, at the end, I have to multiply `(128,3,49,32)` with clustered matrix that has `(X,49)` shape. It may be in other way. Is there any way to do that? Maybe with einsum?

Comment: @DOLFIN I still do not understand why you thing reshaping will be efficient. It will give incorrect results and still be inefficient. I just gave you a code to multiply two matrices. If you still insist on reshaping, go ahead. You could do `A.reshape(-1, 49)` and have it as you want. But whyyyy??? why would you think that solves the problem?? So you are thinking that if at all you do not first reshape to 49, you will not get correct results. etc.. I do not understand your logic though. Am so sorry

Comment: Let me explain again. I have `(128, 3, 49, 32)` matrix. I am reshaping this matrix to        
`(128 * 3 * 49, 32)` in order to cluster the matrix with the help of its rows. Clustering is necessary for my interest. So, after clustering, I have a matrix that has shape `(X, 32)`. At the end, I have another matrix which has shape like `(128, 3, 32, 49)`. I will make a matrix multiplication of second described matrix and clustered matrix.

Comment: At the end, I will reuse cluster centers in order to finalize my matrix multiplication result matrix such that its shape will be `(128* 3* 49, 49)`. Then I want to reshape this such that finalized matrix result will be `(128, 3, 49, 49)`. So, first of all, I have to achieve matrix multiplication of  `(128* 3* 49, 32)`  and `(128, 3, 32, 49)` so that result matrix is      
 `(128, 3, 49, 49)`. I hope I am more clear right now. Thanks for your kind answers and help.

Comment: @DOLFIN you will have to give an example. I did not understand what you said.  Without an example for one to visualize what you are trying to say, you wont get help. read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a betterquestion